# JDBC not extracting data from my local database

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

I am trying to connect my local database. But it's not doing. I am using NetBeans IDE.Pls, help me to solve this issue. It compiles and says Build successful but no output is coming.

```
public class JDBCProject1 {

public static void main (String[] args){
  try
{
    //2. load / register Driver Manager
    Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");

    //3. establish connecction

    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/JDBC","Project1","Project1");
    System.out.println("Hello");

    //4. prepare statement
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();



    //5. execute statement

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from employees");

    //6. process the result

    while(rs.next())
    {
        int eid = rs.getInt("employeeNumber");
        String ename = rs.getString("lastName");
        //int sal = rs.getInt("salary");
        System.out.println("empid\t"+eid);
        System.out.println("empname\t"+ename);
        //System.out.println("empsalary\t"+sal);

    }


    //7. close connections

    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();
}
catch(Exception e)

{



}

}

}
```

I am trying to connect my local database. But it's not doing. I am using NetBeans IDE.Pls, help me to solve this issue. It compiles and says Build successful but no output is coming.

Comment: Is any exception being thrown?  You don't log anything in your code, so unless you have stepped through with a debugger, you wouldn't know this one way or the other.  Is username/password `Project1` correct credentials?  Can you connect directly to your database using this?

Comment: Don't swallow exceptions. At the very least use a `e.printStackTrace()` in the `catch` block

Comment: The likely cause is you're loading the Derby embedded driver, but then use a Derby client/server URL. But as a_horse says: don't swallow exception, but log them (or use `e.printStackTrace()`), and include the exception stacktrace in your question.

Comment: After adding e.printStackTrace()  in catch block. it gives me this error.run:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoaBUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 15 seconds)

Comment: The EmbeddedDriver is in derby.jar; the Client driver is in derbyclient.jar. Since your connection URL is for the client driver, put derbyclient.jar in your classpath.